# Display shortest path to finish in 2D array

Tags: c#, maze

Hello i need help with my maze solver.
I have code that can search maze and find finish, but now i need to just display the shortest path.
Problem is, my code show every step that my algorithm did.
Can i ask for hint how to display just path i need ?

```
class GFG
{
    static int ROW = 9;
    static int COL = 10;
    static int[,] Maze;


    public class Point
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    };

    public class QueueNode
    {
        public Point pt;

        public int dist;

        public QueueNode(Point pt, int dist)
        {
            this.pt = pt;
            this.dist = dist;
        }
    };


    static bool IsValid(int row, int col)
    {
        return (row >= 0) && (row < ROW) &&
               (col >= 0) && (col < COL);
    }




    static int PathFind(Point start, Point end, int[,] mat)
    {

        if (mat[start.x, start.y] != 1 ||
            mat[end.x, end.y] != 1)
            return -1;


        Stack<QueueNode> stack = new Stack<QueueNode>();
        bool[,] visited = new bool[mat.GetLength(0), mat.GetLength(1)];


        stack.Push(new QueueNode(start, 0));

        int c;

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            QueueNode node = stack.Pop();
            int x = node.pt.x;
            int y = node.pt.y;
            c = node.dist;
            if (x == end.x && y == end.y)
            {
                Maze[x, y] = 3;
                return c;
            }



            if (IsValid(x, y) && mat[x, y] == 1 && !visited[x, y])
            {
                stack.Push(new QueueNode(new Point(x + 1, y), c + 1));
                stack.Push(new QueueNode(new Point(x - 1, y), c + 1));
                stack.Push(new QueueNode(new Point(x, y + 1), c + 1));
                stack.Push(new QueueNode(new Point(x, y - 1), c + 1));
                Maze[x, y] = 3;


                visited[x, y] = true;
            }

        }

        return -1;

    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int[,] mat =    {{
                          1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
                        { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 },
                        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
                        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
                        { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 }};

        
        Maze = new int[mat.GetLength(0), mat.GetLength(1)];

        Point source = new Point(0, 0);
        Point dest = new Point(8, 9);

        int dist = PathFind(source, dest, mat);


        for (int i = 0; i < Maze.GetLength(0); ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Maze.GetLength(1); ++j)
            {
                Console.Write(Maze[i, j]);
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        if (dist != -1)
            Console.WriteLine("Shortest Path is " + dist);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Shortest Path doesn't exist");
    }}
```

I have the original field, which I go through the algorithm and another in which I store the coordinates that I have already passed, so it will be marked.
But I would need to mark only the shortest path and not all the steps.

For example this code show:[image: default]

and i need to show just these: [image]

Comment: What you should be storing in each cell is the number of steps away from the end it is.  Then to display a path, start in a cell and repeatedly move to a cell of a lower number until you reach 1 (the end).

Comment: @Wyck And how should i know how far is cell from the end ?

Comment: something like:  instead of `Maze[x, y] = 3` do  `Maze[x, y] = node.dist + 1`  Making sure you start from the end and queue the **ending** node first with a distance of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Maze[x, y] = 3;
Maze[x, y] = node.dist+1;
```

from endPoint to startPoint, every cell will have cost.

The shortest path can be found by finding the neighbor with the smallest value for each cell you are currently on.